# MongoDB, forEach & Promise : How to know when a forEach loop is done?

Tags: mongodb, foreach, promise

In order to output a CSV file, I want to build an array of data from a MongoDB collection.

I use `forEach` into a `promise` and I want to `resolve` when all the records have been read.

However my code below does not work. The `promise` is never resolved. It seems there is a bug with the `if/else` condition. Is there another way to know when the `forEach` loop is done?

```
exports.eachRecord = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var data = []
    mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO, function (err, db) {
      // Handled connection error
      if (err) { return console.log(err) }
      db.collection('log').find().forEach(function (doc) {
        if (doc !== null) {
          console.log(doc.ug)
          data.push(doc.ug)
        } else {
          db.close()
          console.log('done!')
          resolve(data)
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Any idea?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The `mongodb`, since v3.0, support the [`cursor.forEach(iterator, endCallback)`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Cursor.html#forEach)

We must distinguish between:

- array.forEach: it is sync and iterate an array of elements all loaded in memory after the `toArray`
- mongoCursor.forEach: it is async and it is managed by the mongo driver. You are streaming the data, so you can put them to a file or to an http response.

So to archive your needsyou need only to add a callback:

```
    exports.eachRecord = function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const data = []
        mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO, function (err, db) {
          if (err) { return reject(err) }

          db.collection('log').find().forEach(
            doc => { data.push(doc.ug) },
            err => {
              if (err) { return reject(err) }
              resolve(data)
            })
        })
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var data = db.collection('credit_history').find({
            'history.dt': '2019-04-25'
        }).toArray((err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(res);
        });
    }).catch((ex)=>{
        console.log(ex);
    });
}

   var array_data =[] ;
        var data = await getData().then((data)=>{
            data.forEach((el)=>{
                console.log(el.p);
                array_data.push(el.p) ;

            })
        });
```

Comment: `toArray()` method is slow and should not be used for big data sets. It's better to get documents asynchronously in batches, as the proposed solution would not be able to e.g. fetch data sets that are bigger than default NodeJS memory cap by default.

It's always better to use either `forEach()` or `next()` to get the data from cursor.

Answer (score 0):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is synchronous.

The problem is with your mongodb call, which is not asynchronous. You can make it asynchronous by adding it a callback.

```
db.collection('log').find({}, (err, data) => {
  if (error) ...
  data.forEach((doc) => { ... });
  // Whatever you want to do after forEach.
});
```